# Is Map.entry (Java) the best equivalent to the .Net Tuple?

Tags: java, tuples

I am porting a .NET RESTful server (no UI) to Java 8. It looks like the best equivalent of [Tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-2?view=netcore-3.1) (I use it a lot) is Map.entry. I don't see any downside to this, it's just a weird use of the class.

Comment: I would refrain from using Map.Entry. At best, it'll be confusing. There's no harm in creating your own Tuple class.

Comment: I agree with @MichaelBianconi. I find code using pair and tuple classes really difficult to read, as they don't tell you what's in them.

Answer (score 1):

It really isn't a good class to use.

There is nothing stopping you from creating your own `Tuple<A,B>` class. But there is a reason why Java doesn't include one -- in general, types should have meaningful names. "Tuple" isn't really telling you *what* is in the tuple.

If you are using `var nameAndAdress = new Tuple<>(name, address)`, you are relying on the name of the variable telling you *what* the tuple is. As soon as you assign this tuple to another variable, you lose that information. Even worse, you lose type safety, since you can assign *any* similar tuple to this variable. Creating an explicit `NameAndAddress` class avoids this pitfall.

Yes, you might end up with a few more classes - but you actually get idiomatic Java code that other devs can readily use instead of trying to port foreign idioms to Java.

Abusing `Map.Entry` is even worse, as a typical Java dev would not expect to see `Map.Entry` outside of, you know, a map.

So, prefer meaningful types over a generic tuple class, and both of those over `Map.Entry`.

<sub>As a side note: Records will likely help a lot in reducing boilerplate for creating such classes. Alternatively, use Lombok.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

A route that may be helpful instead of trying to utilize the `Map.Entry` class would be to use some common Java libraries that supply a `Tuple` type. This is a [good article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-pairs) outlining different libraries/approaches that are widely used in the Java community to supplement the absence of `Tuples`. Examples are libraries like Apache Commons, which provides a mutable/immutable tuple, or Vavr which is a functional library that provides immutable tuples. I have used both of these previous libraries, and have found them to be very useful.